# How to change colour of ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I have a list which contains hardcoded items which bydefault comes in white colour which is almost invisible with my whitebackground.
public class Message extends ListFragment {

```
/** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
String android_versions[] = new String[]{
    "Jelly Bean",
    "IceCream Sandwich",
    "HoneyComb",
    "Ginger Bread",
    "Froyo"     
};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);

    /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a Custom Layout for ListviewAdapter instead of using Default, Refer the Below Link for more Understanding [Link] (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: Is there any other easier way.. that doc contains no code for changing text colour

Comment: Okie,,, Check This One :- (http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516) .                               Very Simple tutorial but you have to do the one change :-  Using By default Layout make your own. Try to understand not need to make custom adpater just make layout .R.layout.OWNLAYOUT

Comment: In Own Layout - just define one Textview  Like Below :- (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.decimal.kotak.utils.BrandTextView android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:textColor="#000000" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:gravity="left|center_vertical" android:textSize="16sp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>)

Comment: right now with my above given code i am calling this class with my tabs like tab1 .setTabListener(new CustomTabListener<Contacts>(this, "android", Contacts.class)); how to call your class

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be copying the code in *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice* into your own layout resource and customizing it.

In Android-v22 this code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd" />
```

And then you can pass your own customized resource to the ArrayAdapter constructor:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.my_simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the baseadapter with custom view, It is easy way to change the color in custom view

Refer Example : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Answer (score 0):

for your requirement you should change custom adapter instead of default: here you may find the some help:

```
public class CustomUsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
public CustomUsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> users) {
    super(context, 0, users);
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    User user = getItem(position);    
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    tvName.setText(user.name);
    tvName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
}
```

you need a model that use as a data type in your array

```
public class User {
public String name;

public User(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public static ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User("Jelly Bean"));
    users.add(new User("IceCream Sandwich"));
    users.add(new User("HoneyComb"));
    users.add(new User("Ginger Bread"));
    return users;
}
}
```

in your fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

ArrayList<User> arrayOfUsers = User.getUsers();
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    CustomUsersAdapter adapter = new CustomUsersAdapter(getActivity(), arrayOfUsers);
    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Now you are able to change the color of background or textColor dynamically in Java or in XML "item_user"

Answer (score 0):

you have to put below code in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

  <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>

</style>
```